# I want to leave Stack Overflow and take my teams with me

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams, accounts

I want to delete my account. However, I can't because I am a member (administrator) of a team.

[image]

I am the only member of that team and therefore can't leave it.

[image]

I signed up to it during the September promotion to see what it was like, but I have not deployed it across my organisation yet, and during the current climate here I do not plan to do so.

I am also not creating a throwaway account just so I can invite it and leave. What are my options here?

Comment: Just use the Contact Us link at the bottom of every page and explain what you need help with.

Comment: @rene Thanks, I've now done that. I was hoping there would be a simpler solution - having to use the contact form to request this seems unnecessary.

Comment: Yeah, it is fair to assume all edge cases are covered. Given the size of the dev team on SE they might not have foreseen that your usecase would be a blocking factor. The question is fine and assuming you don't want to wait for 6 to 8 weeks to have this fixed, contact us is the route to go. The staff handling those are friendly and helpful in the cases I had to involve them. Take care!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are correct, we cannot delete your account while it is the sole admin of a Team. Before we can delete your account, we'd have to delete your Team, and this can only be done through an automated process:

1. A Teams subscription is cancelled.
2. Once cancelled and the remaining billing period ends, we start a 60-day countdown.
3. 60 days from the last active date, we hard delete all Teams data.

To start this process, please go into your admin settings and cancel your Teams subscription. Once 60 days have passed from the last active date (for instance, if you cancel with 15 days left in the billing period, the deletion will occur in 75 days), please contact support@stackoverflow.com to have your SO account deleted.

Comment: Does it mean the user will not be able to delete his account for at least 60 days?

Comment: @Trilarion That is correct.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation. A potential of 90 days seems excessive for account removal - is there any way to expedite this other than a [GDPR](https://ico.org.uk/for-organisations/guide-to-data-protection/guide-to-the-general-data-protection-regulation-gdpr/individual-rights/right-to-erasure#ib11) request (which is 30 days)? I'm not going to, as I'm in no rush - but it might be useful information for future users.

Comment: @Juice hey - any follow up to my previous comment?

Comment: @lewis At the moment there is no way to expedite the process except for a GDPR request. Please keep in mind, this is an edge case because you are the sole admin of a team. In all other cases, a deletion request would be much faster if not instantaneous.

Comment: A Product Support Manager. That's a good idea. Is this a new role?

Comment: I canceled the subscription of the team but it will end in 6 months!!? I am also the only admin.