# Is the Account Removal process GDPR Compliant?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams, accounts, personal-data, gdpr

*This is a follow up to my [previous question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390715/i-want-to-leave-stack-overflow-and-take-my-teams-with-me) regarding leaving Stack Overflow when you're part of a team and a comment I left under the answer:*

> Thank you for the confirmation. A potential of 90 days seems excessive
>   for account removal - is there any way to expedite this other than a
>   GDPR request (which is 30 days)? I'm not going to, as I'm in no rush -
>   but it might be useful information for future users.

Unfortunately, it seems my comment isn't visible enough for an answer so I'm asking it again here. My question is as quoted above really;

1. Do I really have to wait the 90 days to close my account?
2. Is this [GDPR compliant](https://ico.org.uk/for-organisations/guide-to-data-protection/guide-to-the-general-data-protection-regulation-gdpr/individual-rights/right-to-erasure#ib11)? GDPR recommends 30 days between request and deletion.
3. Would a GDPR request even speed this process up?

Comment: Doesn't GDPR allow additional time when the request receiver can explain to you why it takes longer?.... Ok, that's covered in *"Can we extend the time for a response?"* and allows up to three months in total. But the actual question is: who's going to sue SE for that if they don't comply to your request in time?

Comment: @Tom Yes, they can extend it with a reasonable explanation. I don’t suppose many people will sue them over it (I certainly won’t) but it still doesn’t sit right with me.

Comment: @Tom no one needs to sue anyone. This is a EU directive and breaches of this are handled by the EU who issue fines to companies that do no comply

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have now had a reply to my comment as follows;

> At the moment there is no way to expedite the process except
>   for a GDPR request. Please keep in mind, this is an edge case because
>   you are the sole admin of a team. In all other cases, a deletion
>   request would be much faster if not instantaneous.

This implies;

1. Yes, I have to wait the 90 days
2. They can remove the account faster if a GDPR request is made.